# Искажение ссылок фиксированной частью NavLink JS

Tags: javascript, react-router-dom

Использую NavLink для формирования адресной строки. В одной из компонент url формируется по шаблону:

```
<NavLink to={"/Dialogs/" + props.id}>{props.name}</NavLink>
```

Что даёт ожидаемый результат: http://localhost:3000/Dialogs/3

Но после этого все прочие ссылки на разделы сайта, определённые в коде таким образом:

```
 <NavLink to='News' >News</NavLink>
```

в браузере превращаются в href='/Dialogs/News'

Но после правки адресной строки в ручную - всё снова работает как положено

Как заставить react изменять весь url при его переопределении? И почему может появиться фиксированная часть адреса?

Весь проект тут: https://github.com/jelka2008/SocialNet

Answer (score 0):

Забыли слэш `<NavLink to='/News'>News</NavLink>`

Comment: Так и есть. Сперва решила, что только при написании вопроса ошиблась, но оказалось, что и в коде. Большое спасибо!